# Specialization of template function after point of use will break the compilation

Tags: c++, specialization, language-lawyer, template-function

Consider next example :

```
#include <iostream>

template< int a >
void foo();

int main(int argn, char* argv[])
{
    foo<1>();
}

template<>
void foo<1>()
{
    std::cout<<1<<std::endl;
}
```

The compilation fails with next error messages :

```
rg.cpp:12: error: specialization of ‘void foo() [with int a = 1]’ after instantiation
```

What paragraph in the standard explains this error?

PS :I know that if I move the function definition in front of main will make the error go away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that's *undefined behavior* according to the standard.  There are no restrictions on what a toolchain can do in cases of UB, generating a compiler error is one of the friendlier possibilities.

---

Section `[temp.spec]`, 14.7p5 says

> For a given template and a given set of *template-arguments*,
>
> - an explicit instantiation deﬁnition shall appear at most once in a program,
> - an explicit specialization shall be deﬁned at most once in a program (according to 3.2), and
> - both an explicit instantiation and a declaration of an explicit specialization shall not appear in a
>     program unless the explicit instantiation follows a declaration of the explicit specialization.
>
> An implementation is not required to diagnose a violation of this rule.

Section `[temp.expl.spec]` 14.7.3p6 says:

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then **that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place**, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

---

Your program violates these requirements.