# specialize type_trait after base class = undefine behavior?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, template-specialization, type-traits

I want to enable user to control "internal type" of base class.  This code works fine.

**Version 1** ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a6940073f816550))

```
//library layer
template<class Derived> class BT_trait{
    public: using type=int;  
};
template<class Derived> class BT{
    public: using typee=typename BT_trait<Derived>::type;
    public: typee f(){ return 1;}
};
//user code below
class C;
template<> class BT_trait<C>{
    public: using type=std::string;  //<-- user want to set "internal type"
};
class C : public BT<C> {
    public: typee f(){ return "OK";}
};
int main(){
    C bt;
    std::cout<< bt.f();
}
```

If I make it a little more complex by adding a template parameter, it will not  compilable anymore.
 (show below)

**Version 2** ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbe4cda7bb593c55))

```
template<class Derived> class BT_trait{
    public: using type=int;  
};
template<class Derived,class Dummy> class BT{
    public: using typee=typename BT_trait<Derived>::type;
    public: typee f(){ return 1;}
};
//user code below
template<class T> class C;
template<class T> class BT_trait<C<T>>{
    public: using type=std::string;  
};
template<class T> class C : public BT<C<T>,T> {
    // public: typename BT<C<T>, T>::typee f(){ return "OK";} //Version #2b 
    public: typee f(){ return "OK";}  //Version #2a
    //^ error: 'typee' does not name a type; did you mean 'wctype'?
};
int main(){
    C<int> bt;
    std::cout<< bt.f();
}
```

But if I use `#2b` (dirty) instead of `#2a` (concise), the above code will work fine.
Why?  Is it possible to make `#2a` work?

According to a quote from [Specialization of template function after point of use will break the compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912689/specialization-of-template-function-after-point-of-use-will-break-the-compilatio) :-

> Section [temp.expl.spec] 14.7.3p6 : If a template, a member
>   template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized
>   then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of
>   that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take
>   place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no
>   diagnostic is required.

I doubt that my code is undefined behavior.  Correct?
I am very new to template specialization.

Comment: Works for me, and i don't understand why do you need to use Dummy parameter in `class BT`?

Comment: @Yola Are you using VS?

Comment: @Angew yes.....

Comment: @Yola VS doesn't do two-phase lookup properly, so it parses the code even if a conforming compiler does not.

Comment: @Yola  In real case, I want `Dummy` and many template parameters. (not shown)  XD

Comment: This does not work in VS2017 with default settings (`/permissive-`).

Comment: @VTT `/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /W4 /Zc:wchar_t /I"c:\Yola\boost_1_65_1\" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"x64\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\Vc17Test.pch" /diagnostics:classic `

Comment: @VTT VS 2010 and below will happily compile this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your code does not exhibit UB, and will not even when made to compile.

The problem is that once `C` becomes a template, the two-phase lookup rule starts to apply inside it. Basically, names which do not depend on template parameters are looked up when the template is parsed, at which point in time the argument for `T` is of course unknown and the compiler thus cannot look into `BT<C<T>, T>` and find `typee` defined there. So it fails.

You have to mark `typee` as a dependent name (because it *does* depend on `T`). You have several ways:

- Qualify it when referring to it:

  ```
  public: typename C::typee f(){ return "OK";}
  ```

  [[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9707095077131d83)
- Bring it into your class' scope (as also suggested by [VTT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146301/1782465)):

  ```
  using typename BT<C<T>, T>::typee;
  public: typee f(){ return "OK";}
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `typee` type depends on template parameters. As an option you can make `typee` recognizable as is by adding using directive:

```
using typename BT<C<T>, T>::typee;
public: typee f(){ return "OK";}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1dpEOMiIpLN4VKax)

Comment: Thank, but why the line `using` is need?  It is dirty. I believe (for the compiler) I was clear enough at the base class `BT`.

Comment: @cppBeginner No, it's not dirty at all; it's normal template programming. See my answer for an explanation.